# How to send an array of objects to node/mongoose via req.body

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to send an array of objects to update data in mongodb - if I hard code the data in a const on node.js it works just fine, however I can't work out how to send the data in postman and get the same result?

```
newOpeningHours = [{
                "_id": 1,
                "dayOfWeek": 1,
                "friendlyName": 'Lundi',
                "openingHour": 7,
                "openingMinute": 30,
                "closingHour": "02",
                "closingMinute": "30"
            },
"_id": 2,
                "dayOfWeek": 2,
                "friendlyName": 'Mardi',
                "openingHour": 7,
                "openingMinute": 30,
                "closingHour": "02",
                "closingMinute": "30"
            }

]
```

The above directly in node works just fine, how can I replicate the same thing so that my front-end sends the data in a similar way so it actually works? I am trying with postman so I can work out what my react front-end will need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the body tab, select "raw", paste your JSON and select JSON (application/json) so the header "Content-Type": "application/json" is added:

[image: Image from https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests/]